# If I replace finitely many digits of $e$ with any number(s), is the new number transcendental?

Tags: real-analysis

In general, if finitely many digits of a transcendental number are replaced by different numbers, is the resulting number also transcendental?

Comment: He said finitely many

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The resulting number is the sum of $\mathrm e$ and some rational number. Hence it must be transcendental. (Otherwise $\mathrm e$ is algebraic)

Comment: Thank you for your answer!